# Web Api ResponseType of System.Web.Http.Results

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a .Net Web Api application, and one of the Actions has an output of `Task<IHttpActionResult>`.

The action's response can be either be - `System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestResult` or `System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult`.

I want to put an appropriate type inside the `typeof()` in the attribute `[ResponseType(typeof())]` to indicate what the action returns.

What should go inside the parenthesis of the `typeof()`?

Here is what my code currently looks like in my Controller -

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof (*NEED SOMETHING HERE*))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutAsync(MyClass myClass)
    {
        var success =  await _myRepository.TrySomething(myClass);
        if (!success)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Your method isn't returning any data outside of that Response. The type of the data returned from the method is what would go in there, so if the method was returning an integer(You are doing a put, so maybe you are returning the id of the item being added to you system), then it would be [ResponseType(typeof (int))]
As you have it coded now, though, I don't think you need that attribute at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response peinearydevelopment! I need an attribute because I have a Help Page which indicates what the response would be and right now it displays "IHttpActionResult" which is not correct.

Comment: Ok, but did my response answer your question or is there more that still needs to be clarified?

Comment: I guess what you are saying is the answer to my problem, Thanks, peinearydevelopment.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[ResponseType(typeof(void))]`
This indicates an empty response.